# Neighborhood boundaries and building footprints for Johannesburg?

Tags: shapefile, footprint, data, south-africa

Are there any sources for free (or commercial) and distributable neighborhood and building footprint datasets for Johannesburg out there?

I've already looked on:

- Google
- OpenStreetMap
- joburg.org.za
- demarcation.org.za
- sa-venues.com
- SOCIOECONOMIC DATA AND APPLICATIONS CENTER (SEDAC)
- geoscience.org.za
- gadm.org

and probably some more that I do not remember right now...

Comment: What do you mean by free (or commercial). I'm sure for the right price someone will classify some air photos/satellite imagery for you :D Did you ever find an answer to this?